# Apply FixedColumns to multiple tables on page

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

FixedColumns extension (3.1.0) for jQuery DataTables (1.10.9) only affects the first of multiple tables on my page.

Whereas, the datatable plug-in has applied the rest of its rules to all of the tables on my page.

Here is how I've set up my plug-in:

```
var datatables_options = {
        "bAutoWidth": true,
        "sDom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">',
        "bPaginate": false,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "bSort": true,
        "bFilter": false,
        "aaSorting": [],
        "bInfo": false,
        "bStateSave": false,
        "iCookieDuration": 0,
        "bScrollAutoCss": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bJQueryUI": false,
        "sScrollY": "475px",
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "sScrollXInner": "150%"
    };
var fixedColumnTable = $("table.dataTable").DataTable(datatables_options);
new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(fixedColumnTable);
```

Comment: What version of jQuery DataTables are you using?

Comment: DataTables 1.10.9 and FixedColumns 3.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Use [`fixedColumns: true`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/fixedColumns) initialization option instead to initialize multiple tables.

```js
var datatables_options = {
    "fixedColumns": true,
    "bAutoWidth": true,
     // ... skipped ...
};
```

Remove the line below as it is not needed:

```
new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(fixedColumnTable);
```

Apparently it is by design that `$.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns` initializes only one table.

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzj6zgbk/5/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my tables currently work like this.
What I want is for the left hand column to freeze on each of the tables. Currently it only does this on the first table. (All tables share the class name "dataTable" as the documentation)

Comment: @Kelsall, I wasn't clear in my answer, added more details. Please see [my example](https://jsfiddle.net/mzj6zgbk/5/) and how both tables have first column fixed.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot! This has now applied the fixed column to all four of my tables.
I was wondering whether you could help with another issue that seems to have occurred after removing this code?
When the page loads the tables are not visible (table wrapper height is set to 0) but after resizing the window, the table becomes visible again.
I'm using bootstrap, so maybe there's a known js conflict?

Comment: I have fixed the above issue. It was related to a div class.
@Gyrocode.com Do you know anything about the header element widths not aligning with the table content elements? Following a window resize the widths are set automatically and align with the table contents